# can't stop nameerror in python

Tags: python, nameerror

When I type this...

```
class doorsprite(Sprite):
     def __init__(self, game, photo_image, x, y, width, height):
            Sprite.__init__(self, game)
            self.photo_image = photo_image
            self.image = game.canvas.create_image(x, y, \
                    image=self.photo_image, anchor='nw')
            self.coordinates = Coords(x, y, x + (width / 2), y + height)
            self.endgame = True
```

I get...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\telta\Desktop\stickman game.py", line 94, in <module>
    class DoorSprite(Sprite):
NameError: name 'Sprite' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you make sure that the `Sprite` class is defined above this one?

Comment: it says `Sprite` is not defined, and you haven't shown us where you defined it

Comment: Where does `Sprite` come from? Is it defined in some other file? Then you need to [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-importing) it. Is it defined in the same file? Then please show us your complete code.

Comment: Your error and your code don't match each other: do you have `class doorsprite(Sprite):` or `class DoorSprite(Sprite):`? (But that's just a side comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably reading this from book ***A playful introduction on programming***
You are missing out on the Sprite class which is given on later in the book.
You can go back and search for the sprite function.
Have fun building stickman game.
Thank you.

Comment: would you be able to answer the new Question  I posted?

Answer (score 0):

You never defined `Sprite` within an accessible scope for your class. This is likely the result of a neglected/faulty import.